# Is there a hidden throughput limit (perhaps per bucket?) on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

It seems like Google Cloud storage can upload 500MB data in about 3 seconds (parallel upload) to 6 seconds (single-threaded upload), as per the 2nd graph in this link: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas

This translates, for the single-threaded upload case, to 500MB * 8 bits/byte / 6seconds  = ~0.7Gbs

However, I'm confused: if my computer (in this case, a Google VM with 16 cores) can achieve anywhere from 10GBs (sustained) to 16Gbs (peak), can I upload *multiple* files (let's say ~20), and max out my computer's bandwidth (eg ~10 to ~16Gbs) and Google cloud storage would be able receive my data at that rate? (For simplicity, let's assume that the object names for these 20 objects are all very nicely distinct and so we're not getting into the "name contention" problem that Google suggests we avoid. And, if it makes a difference, the object blob sizes can be reasonably large, eg > 1 MB, so that we don't need to consider transmission overheads etc.)

If the answer is no, I'm guessing that Google Cloud Storage (and presumably S3 as well) places some max limit on the bandwidth for a single bucket? Or at least it places limits on total bandwidth originating from a single MAC address? (If so, what happens if the upload requests originate from different GCE VMs (with different MAC addresses & IPs etc? Would the aggregate bandwidth still be limited to under 2 Gbs? Is there anything we can do to lift this limit, if one truly exists?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCS does have some API rate limits [[1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas),[2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate)], but ultimately with the right usage patterns GCS can scale very high. At some point you will eventually hit infrastructural limits, at which point you need to talk to Google's sales team to plan what capacity you will need.

However this point is far *far* above what a single VM is capable of. You should be able to saturate a single VMs network.

Comment: Thank you. So, would you have any instincts as to whether even a very large number of GCE VMs (eg 100) each with 8 cores so that *each* of the 100 nodes can individually hit 10GBs (sustained) to 16GBs (peak) can all read from *800 different* blobs (with very different names, so that we don't get into name contentions) on GCS at a sustained total aggregate rate of 100 * 10GBs = 1000GBs? Or, is the (default) limit more like 100Gbs? (Ie we can only have 10 GCE VMs operating at peak capactiy)? Also, irrespective of your answer to to the 100 node query, why is it that:

Comment: a single upload (even when using "composite" (ie parallel) uploads), can only achieve approximately 2.1Gbs, given that you implied that GCS is "far far above" what a single VM is capable of? Also, for **READING** blobs (instead of the harder writing scenario), if we issue "range" queries (so that we can read from different offsets from a single large blob), and assuming those queries occur on *multiple* threads from multiple nodes, can we achieve a higher total aggregate throughput even those we're still, technically, reading from the same blob (but just at different offsets). @David

Comment: I am also thinking on same line is there any hidden setting for download / upload throughput on google cloud storage / cloud run ?.
With 2 cpu and 4 GB memory it take 13 sec to download  (100 % cpu utilization)
Increased 4 cpu and 8 GB memory still its downloads at 13 sec . I tried it with different worker and chunk sizes
i am using transfer manager to download in parallel in python.